# How to detect closed StreamSocket at client side

Tags: c#, tcp, uwp

DataReader.LoadAsync does not detect closed sockets (with InputStreamOptions::Partial)

I am sending data to server via TCP connection and read the response but after and everything is working here. But after 5-6 message my project is hand I didn't find where is error.

Some time i found that connection is closed via host machine
so **How can i found that is StreamSocket  is connected or not**

============Code=============

```
public async Task<bool> Connect(string host, string port)
        {
            try
            {
                socket = new StreamSocket();
                HostName hostName = new HostName(host);
                CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                _cts.CancelAfter(5000);

                // Connect to the server
                await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, port).AsTask(_cts.Token);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }


        }


      public async Task<String> SendMessageToServer(string message)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Create the data writer object backed by the in-memory stream. 
                    using (writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream))
                    {
                        writer.WriteString(message);
                        await writer.StoreAsync();
                        await writer.FlushAsync();
                        writer.DetachStream();
                        return await ReadResponse();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw ex;
                }

            }
            private async Task<String> ReadResponse()
            {
                DataReader reader;
                StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                try
                {
                    using (reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream))
                    {
                        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;
                        // If task cancellation was requested, comply
                        //cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        // Set InputStreamOptions to complete the asynchronous reask(cancellationToken);
                        reader.InputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.Partial;

                        IAsyncOperation<uint> taskLoad = reader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength);
                        taskLoad.AsTask().Wait(2000);

                        string msg = string.Empty;
                        while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
                        {
                            strBuilder.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));
                            msg = strBuilder.ToString();
                        }

                        reader.DetachStream();
                        reader.Dispose();

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    return "0";
                    throw ex;

                }
                finally
                {
                    // Cleanup once complete


                }
                return strBuilder.ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i found that is StreamSocket is connected or not

I tested your code on my side. DataReader/DataWriter are not concerned with "connections" themself as you known. But the connection closed will be detected  by method [Task.Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270644(v=vs.110).aspx),  which is for synchronized waiting on the task completed or throw exceptions. So in your scenario, if the `StreamSocked` is closed before [`DataReader.LoadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/windows.storage.streams.datareader.loadasync.aspx), the `taskLoad.AsTask().Wait(2000);` will throw the exception:

> One or more errors occurred. (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. )

If the socket connection is closed during `DataReader.LoadAsync` processed, this time the client cannot detect the closing, it will detect the connection closed next time the client send message to server. In your scenario client will continue sending messages to server which will always catch the connection closing when send new messages. You will got connection closed exception at `await writer.StoreAsync();` code line if the server close the connection.

> But after 5-6 message my project is hand I didn't find where is error

You may have catch the exception about connection closing. So this may lead by some other reasons. I saw the `DataReader` in your code snippet only load message one time for length 1024. So if the message send from server is longer than 1024, the client will receive only partial message, and next time when server send new message, the client will still receive the remain message from the last time not the new message. After several times server will back log many data and may lead issues. I recommend you to update the `reader.LoadAsync` code as follows:

```
  string msg = string.Empty;  
  var loadsize = await reader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength);
  while (loadsize >= ReadBufferLength)
  {
      loadsize = await reader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength);
  }
  if (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
  {
      strBuilder.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));
  }
```

Addtionaly, I strongly recommend you to use [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which will not have the concern as `DataReader` has, And your `ReadResponse()` method can just be simply as follows:

```
private async Task<String> ReadResponse()
{
    Stream streamIn = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(streamIn);
    string response = await reader2.ReadLineAsync();
    return response; 
}
```

More details about StreamSocket in uwp please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket).