# Parsing variable-sized packets

Tags: c#, uwp, network-protocols

I'm working on a multiplayer game and I'm having an issue with the the way I parse the packets from the connection. When I'm debugging the game it runs at a lower performance and the packets are received, when I'm not, packets aren't fully received and the ParsePacket method isn't called.

My packet structure is this:

> 2 Bytes Short Command, 2 Bytes Short Payload Size, (Optional) Payload Bytes

```
IInputStream inputStream = null;
DataReader dataReader = null;

byte[] data = new byte[1024];
IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();

try
{
    inputStream = StreamSocket.InputStream;

    dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
    dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
    dataReader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

    while (connected)
    {
        await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 1024, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
        Debug.WriteLine("Buffer " + buffer.Length);

        if (buffer.Length >= PacketHeaderSize)
        {
            short command = dataReader.ReadInt16();
            short payloadSize = dataReader.ReadInt16();
            byte[] payload = null;

            if (payloadSize == 0)
            {
                UpdateBuffer(buffer, (uint)(PacketHeaderSize + payloadSize));

                Packet packet = new Packet(command, payloadSize, payload);
                ParsePacket(packet);
            }
            else if (payloadSize > 0)
            {
                if (buffer.Length >= (PacketHeaderSize + payloadSize))
                {
                    payload = new byte[payloadSize];
                    dataReader.ReadBytes(payload);

                    UpdateBuffer(buffer, (uint)(PacketHeaderSize + payloadSize));

                    Packet packet = new Packet(command, payloadSize, payload);
                    ParsePacket(packet);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
}

private void UpdateBuffer(IBuffer buffer, uint bytesRead)
{
    if (buffer.Length > bytesRead)
    {
        byte[] bufferBytes = new byte[buffer.Length - bytesRead];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer.ToArray(), (int)bytesRead, bufferBytes, 0, (int)(buffer.Length - bytesRead));
        buffer = bufferBytes.AsBuffer();
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] bufferBytes = new byte[1024];
        buffer = bufferBytes.AsBuffer();
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When writing uwp apps please make sure you have the uwp tag on the question, the classes available from the framework for uwp apps are different than desktop apps.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain My bad, thank you.

Comment: It's impossible to know for sure without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, but your code appears to have the standard mistake made by pretty much anyone who doesn't bother to study network protocols before diving into network code: you are expecting all of the data to be received all at the same time. That's not how TCP works. The socket is a stream of bytes, and the data can be delivered in as few as a single byte at a time (though in practice it's not usually that bad :) ).

Comment: In any given state of the consumption of the bytes, you need to keep reading until you have all the bytes you need. Given the code you posted, it's a bit odd that `ParsePacket()` isn't called _at all_, but it's certainly reasonable to expect that it might be called with incomplete data, because you do nothing to ensure you've read data until you get as much was expected. There is also the issue that you could read the next message's header as part of the current message, corrupting the data stream.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I knew about the mixed packets or incomplete data, my main concern was over complicating my code but I've updated the code on my question. I'm quite lost on how to append the current stream of bytes to the buffer though. Thank you.

Comment: Have you resolved your issue ? Did you mean you don't have the issue when  debugging? What' the buffer length you read when you are not under debugging and have the issue?

Comment: Nope! Sadly I can't tell how to update the buffer once I read a packet from it so it doesn't get read again. I think I need another buffer since the one that IBuffer is using isn't updating.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I forgot to mention you in the comment, see above. Thamks!

Comment: Did you have issues under debug mode? If as you described, it should also have issues under debug mode. By the way check if [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404185/how-to-detect-closed-streamsocket-at-client-side) can help.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT the code from your question has been really helpful, it made me realize two important issues that I've fixed now. I posted my own answer as now it's working perfectly, thank you. P.S. Issues from debug mode may be due game running slower than normal so less packets were being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things fixed to make this work:

- Take important variables outside the parsing packets loop as we need the value next time we need to parse another packet.
- Read the packet header once if a incomplete app or game packet is received.
- Load **only** the bytes we need
- Read the header and payload once it has been fully received using *UnconsumedBufferLength*.

Code:

```
short command = 0;
short payloadSize = 0;
byte[] payload = null;

bool packetHeaderRead = false;

while (connected)
{
    if (!packetHeaderRead)
    {
        if (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength < PacketHeaderSize)
        {
            int headerBytesLeft = PacketHeaderSize - (int)dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength;

            if (headerBytesLeft > 0)
            {
                await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)headerBytesLeft);
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            command = dataReader.ReadInt16();
            payloadSize = dataReader.ReadInt16();
            packetHeaderRead = true;
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int payloadBytesLeft = payloadSize - (int)dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength;

        if (payloadBytesLeft > 0)
        {
            await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)payloadBytesLeft);
        }

        if (payloadSize == 0)
        {
            Packet packet = new Packet(command, payloadSize, payload);
            ParsePacket(packet);

            packetHeaderRead = false;
        }
        else if (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength >= payloadSize)
        {
            payload = new byte[payloadSize];
            dataReader.ReadBytes(payload);

            Packet packet = new Packet(command, payloadSize, payload);
            ParsePacket(packet);

            packetHeaderRead = false;
        }
    }
}
```